# 13'' 2011 MacBook Air: Stuck at blank gray screen, no boot option working

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, recovery

I have a 13" 2011 MacBook Air A1369 stuck on a grey screen. When I startup I can hear the chime and the computer proceed to go to a blank gray screen immediately. The screen has no Apple logo or loading bar.

What I have tried till now:

- Booting in recovery by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Booting in single-user mode by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Booting in verbose mode by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Booting in Safe mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Booting in hardware diagnosis mode by holding <kbd>D</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Resetting PRAM by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.
- Resetting SMC by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> while pressing the power button, then pressing the power button alone -- no effect, blank screen.
- Choosing another booting drive or recovery partition by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> -- no effect, blank screen.

Is there something else I could try to get past this gray screen?

Comment: Looks like you have tried pretty much everything. Unfortunately it may be time to take it to an Apple Store or other trusted local hardware service center.

Comment: Is it possible that a broken SSD might be the problem? looks weird that all the combination keys does nothing, maybe a broken keyboard?

Comment: Absolutely. One of the possibilities. It could be more extreme (bad mobo) or less (loose connector, bad cable). However recovery mode does not boot from the drive, that's all in NVRAM. So if it was just an SSD issue then recovery mode would work and you would not have a target to install to. Yes a bad SSD could be hanging the entire system and preventing any kind of boot, but that will still require diagnosis of the hardware.

Comment: I understand, i have already tried without SSD, makes no difference, external video output same blank screen, is it possible a corrupted BIOS?

Comment: ANYTHING is possible at this point. Take. It. In. For. Service!

Comment: At the moment its not easy for me to bring it into a trusted repair shop, of course apple official service is simply inconvenient for a machine this old, now im gonna try to test keyboard and SSD..

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, the BIOS firmware was badly corrupt from a failed macOS update, i had to fix it hardware removing the BIOS chip and flashing it again, now it's working perfectly!

Comment: how did you flash the bios chip because my laptop has the same issue.

Comment: How did you find the problem? How did you flash the BIOS chip?